Statement execution not ends in Python
When running the below statement that takes more than 30 minutes (31 minutes) using psycopg2 the execution ends in the PostgreSQL server but the python routine not ends:
do $$
declare
  v_minutes int := 31;
begin

  perform pg_sleep(60 * v_minutes);

end $$;

print("start of execution")
try:
    cur  = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(statement)
finally:
    if cur:
        cur.close()
print("end of execution")

In the PostgreSQL logs I got at 30 minutes of execution:
"could not receive data from client: connection reset by peer"
If I run the statement with 29 minutes for example... it works ok.

Please include exactly how you define statement in the Python code.

The error message suggests a server-level timeout of 30 minutes that is independent of either your SQL code or your Python code. (See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164419/is-it-possible-to-limit-timeout-on-postgres-server, for example.)

It also sounds suspiciously like the sort of thing an interfering firewall might do. Which can be a pain to diagnose properly. Configuring keepalive should sort it out though.

The statement keep running in PostgreSQL server even the message in the log until the end.
